# How to send a string value to the action in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I try to send a string value such as '`2016/01/02`' to the action .I fill this date into the href attribute of a tag such as this:

```
 <a href="/Charter/CharterList/@item.FlightDateFull">1111111111</a>
```

but when run my website get error.

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>   Url of this page : http://localhost:40634/Charter/CharterList/13952016/02/02
>   How to fix this?

Comment: Send it as `2016-01-02` and then it will also bind to a parameter which is `DateTime`

Comment: change format to "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  : Thank you .It solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other ways.
But to keep it all simple you can do

```
@item.FlightDateFull.toString("DD-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: All the other options are available on Stack overflow.